# HTML form names to PHP PDO statements

Tags: php, html, pdo

I want to change just one name, or add one form field and I have to do it in 9 different places. Is there a better way to do this? I wonder if maybe I'm doing a lot of work when there is a better way that is half the work.

A code snippet of my code in the files is below. The code is just a snippet, so I know that it isn't complete.

**HTML form**

```
<p>
<label for="fName">First Name</label>
<input id="fName" name="fName" class="required" placeholder="As it appears on your passport" />
<label for="mName">Middle Name</label>
<input id="mName" name="mName" placeholder="As it appears on your passport" />
<label for="lName">Last Name</label>
<input id="lName" name="lName" class="required" placeholder="As it appears on your        passport" />
</p>
```

**PHP PDO statements**

```
$fName = trim($_REQUEST['fName']);
$mName = trim($_REQUEST['mName']);
$lName = trim($_REQUEST['lName']);

$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mform(fname, mname, lname,

..."VALUES(:fname, :mname, :lname,



$query->execute(array(
':fname' => isset($fName) ? $fName : null,
':mname' => isset($mName) ? $mName : null,
':lname' => isset($lName) ? $lName : null,
```

Comment: You should only make 2 changes actually, the input `name` and the $_POST key. What other changes are you making?

Comment: Notepad, find & replace.

Comment: generate the form by code, then generate the query

Comment: [ajaxcrud.com](http://ajaxcrud.com) looks good.. ok, eventually not helpful, but good for easy crud operations.

Comment: P.S. Your code appears to be incomplete. Your `prepare()` and `execute()` functions never conclude... Also, consider re-writing your title to match your new question, and consider further explaining what exactly you're trying to do. It's not completely clear.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia I do have 9 different places for each HTML form field. If I should only have two, where are the two in the code above?

Comment: @Charlie I have done this in the past and it does work, but isn't there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Dagon how are you saying I should generate the code and query, what do you use to do this?

Comment: @animuson The code snippet is incomplete. The entire code is a few pages for each file so I have just selected three fields to display. I've changed the title as well, thanks.

Comment: @user582309 my awesome programming skills

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a complete answer, but there are a few points in your code that can be simplified without any additional "framework" code, just by thinking through the logic.

- any variable that is not set is interpreted as `NULL` automatically, so `isset($fName) ? $fName : null` is somewhat redundant
- in your sanitising code, you're defining each of the variables as you sanitise anyway (e.g. `$fName = trim($_REQUEST['fName'])`), so they will never not be set (they might be empty strings, but that's different)
- if a variable ever *should* be `NULL`, your sanitisation code will know that, and can assign the value explicitly rather than leaving a variable unset
- given the above, your sanitisation can build an associative array of the sanitised values, rather than using separate variables
- since PDO's `execute` understands keys with or without leading `:`, you can use this array directly to substitute the values into the prepared query

.

```
$sanitised_fields['fName'] = isset($_REQUEST['fName']) ? trim($_REQUEST['fName']) : NULL;
// Note that $sanitised_fields can now be passed around as a single variable
//   if you want to break apart sanitisation and SQL into separate functions

// Column names don't have to match array keys, but placeholders do
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mform(first_name) VALUES(:fName)");
$query->execute($sanitised_fields);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much. 

So I could also also change the values in the Insert column to generic values since they don't have to match right? 
`$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO mform(value1, value2) Values(:fName, mName)");`